# select divs by size of underlaying div

Tags: html, select

I have a question about selecting divs through the size of another div.

I have two layers of divs. The top layer contains several small squares (DIV TYPE 1) and the bottom layer just one div with a specific size (DIV TYPE 2).

Now when I 'activate' DIV TYPE 2 (The activation can be a link for example), I want to select only the DIV TYPE 1 squares that are located above DIV TYPE 2, in order to hide them which will make DIV TYPE 2 visible.

[IMG]http://i41.tinypic.com/2ik3zi0.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: i don't understand, put your code plz.

Comment: I haven't made a code yet, because I don't know how I cando it in the best way. To bad I can't add a picture, because my reputation is to low :( Anyway I want my content to be hidden by small puzzle pieces (higher z-index) and when I click on a link, then only the puzzle pieces (also small divs) which are upon the content will be hidden. So is there a way that the puzzle pieces can reconize it they are upon the content and how can i select them?

Comment: add picture link, it s work fine ;)

Comment: if div have the same size, you cannot select div 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/tfGap

Use javascrit and change the z-index property of your div type 1. You need to put absolute position of your div.

HTML

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="type1">type1</div>
  <div id="type2">type2</div>
</div>

<a href="#" onClick="type1()">appear type 1</a> |
<a href="#" onClick="type2()">appear type 2</a>
```

CSS

```
#main {
  background:grey;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-12;
}

#type1{
  position:absolute;
  background: pink;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  z-index:2;

}

#type2{
  position:absolute;
  background: red;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;


}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function type2() {

  document.getElementById('type1').style.zIndex = -3;

}

function type1() {

  document.getElementById('type1').style.zIndex = 2;

}
```

**If you want to desappear div change "style.zIndex = -3;" by "style.display = "none";" in the javascript**